# How to stop texture curving around a hole?

Tags: texturing, uv, unity

I'm developing a game in Unity and I use Blender to create my models. In my game I need a board with holes in it. I create holes by using a cylinder and a boolean modifier like this:
[image: Cylinder]
[image: Board with a hole]

Then I apply my test texture to the board and it looks nice:
[image: Texture]
[image: Textured board with generated coordinates]

By default, the texture mapping coordinates is set to "Generated". But since I want the texture to transfer to Unity, I need to use UV coordinates and create a UV map for the model. I tried to select the top faces and unwrap, but the end result looks messy because the hole makes my texture to curve.
[image: UV mapping the board]
[image: Textured board with UV coordinates]

Is there a simple way to unwrap my board model so that the texture would ignore the hole and look like it did when using generated coordinates? I tried to modify the UV map by selecting different edges from the model and moving the vertices around the UV map but I can't figure out how to do it correctly. I need the texture applied only on the top of my board, if it helps anything.

Or maybe there is some way to import .blend files to Unity with generated coordinates, but I think I have to ask that from the Unity formus instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select upward faces, go in top view and hit <kbd>U</kbd>, Project From View (bounds) to fit the faces to your map, but then the other faces wouldn't be unwrapped, so you'd have to unwrap then separately.

If you're going to export it to Unity, you might as well triangulate the mesh inside Blender with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> before unwrapping, it may work better without NGons.